# How to read from several tables in a single query?

Tags: sqlite, join

In SQLite I have 3 tables `question_table`, `question_description_table`, `option_table` :

```
question_table
Id question1 question2 question3 ...
1  <data>    <data>     <data>   ...
2  <data>    <data>      <data>  ...
3  <data>    <data>      <data>  ...

question_description_table
Id description1 description2 description2 ...
1  <data>          <data>      <data> ...
2  <data>          <data>      <data>...
3  <data>          <data>      <data>...
.
.

option_table
Id option1       option2    option3 ...
1  <data>          <data>     <data> ...
2  <data>          <data>      <data>...
.
.
```

For each question I need data from 3 tables in a single query; for question 1, the query should read from

- `question1` -column in `question_table`,
- `description_table1` column from `description_table`,
- and first four (`option1`, `option2`, `option3`, `option4`) from `option_table` (assuming four options for each question).

I tried below command :

```
SELECT
    question_table.question1,
    question_description_table.description1 
FROM 
    question_table
INNER JOIN
    question_description_table ON question_description_table.id=question_table.id
;
```

Problem is joining option_table with the other two. Is JOIN the solution? If so, how to use it?

Comment: how are these tables connected? Could you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: these tables are connected by common id which is the primary key in each tables.  query should fetch data as this example                                         ex:for question no 1 query should fetch question1 from question_table,description_table1 description_table,and first four table(option1,option2,option3,option4) from option_table (there will be four options for each question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If simply to answer your question then it should be like this:

```
select *
from question_table qt, qustion_description_table qdt, option_table ot
where qt.id = qdt.id and qdt.id = ot.id
```

However, I think you should restructure your tables. So, your `question_table` should contain and `ID`, `QUESTION` and if needed `DESCRIPTION` columns.

```
ID | QUESTION | DESCRIPTION
...    ...        ...
```

Then, your `option_table` could contain `ID`, `QUESTION_ID`, `OPTION` and `CORRECT` (`1` - correct, `0` - incorrect)

```
ID | QUESTION_ID | OPTION | CORRECT
...    ...         ...     ...
```

This way, it's more structured and you can change options for questions(s) by just changing the corresponding `QUESTION_ID`. Also, if you decide to pick options for question(s) you run a simple query:

```
select qt.question, qt.description, ot.option, ot.correct
from question_table qt, option_table ot
where qt.id = ot.question_id and qt.question_id in (...)
```